# React-Native error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have recently started with React-Native and wanted to try a bluetooth connectivity library (https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager)

**Steps to create app and run on device:**

1. react-native init myBluetoothHandler
2. cd myBluetoothHandler
3. npm i --save react-native-ble-manager

When I do this I see this log:
[image]

4. react-native link react-native-ble-manager

Which fails with this error log:
[image]

Just for a hit and try I ran step 3 again and this printed. And after that link command also worked.:
[image]

But I am not able to run the project from Xcode on my device. I see this error:

[image]

Same happened to me when I tried a different library: https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/388

Comment: I just followed your instructions and was able to create, link and build the project without the errors that you were getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHNEE.png

Comment: Also FYI, you aren't using cocoapods in this example, you would have to create a `podfile` and run `pod install` if you were.

Answer (score -2):

Use `react-native init <project_name> --version 0.59.0`. Do not use rc versions.